# Constant expression violates subrange bounds

Tags: указатели, массивы, delphi

Добрый день. Проблема вот в чем.
Создаю динамический массив с помощью `GetMem`; при попытке обратиться к любому его элементу, кроме 1-ого, появляется ошибка

> Constant expression violates subrange bounds.

Что делать?

```
implementation
{$R *.dfm}
{$R-}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
type
arr = array[1..1] of integer; 
 p_arr = ^arr;
var
 a:p_arr;
 size:integer;
begin
 size:=sizeOf(integer);
 GetMem(a,5*size);

 a[2]:=1;//ошибка: Constant expression violates subrange bounds

 FreeMem(a,5*size);

end;

end.
```

Comment: у вас не динамический массив, а массив из одного элемента. динамический массив - это array of integer. и размер для него задается через SetLength

Comment: Yura, этой строчкой выделяется память под 5 элементов массива:

'GetMem(a,5*size);'
 
SetLength преподаватель сказал не использовать.

Comment: Это когда то был такой способ делать динамические массивы. Даже есть `{$R-}` - отключение проверки.

@Wingman если у Вас есть желание именно так делать, просто объявите правильно массив

    arr = array[1..65546] of integer; 

Но проверка на диапазон и помнить размер - за Вами.

Comment: У преподавателя в методичке именно такой код, менять нельзя

    arr = array[1..1] of integer;

У моих одногруппников код работает.

Comment: >У преподавателя в методичке именно такой код, менять нельзя

ох уж эти преподаватели. Уверен, в аду уже стоят отдельные котлы для тех, кто выдумывает эти ограничения. А самый большой котёл с напалмом заготовлен для тех, кто до сих пор парит студентам мозг седьмым делфи

Comment: 7 делфи - это нормально. Вот те, которые впихивают турбопаскаль 5... вот это извращенцы.

Comment: тут, конечно не все так однозначно. Однако против Delphi 7 я бы сказал следующее - за те 12 (или 13) лет, что прошли с момента ее выхода, появилось (и/или улучшилось) множество языков и IDE, куда более удобных и современных, нежели Delphi 7, и вообще утекло очень много воды. Плюс к тому же во многих случаях преподавание таково, что студент на выходе является дипломированным формошлёпом, а не программистом (этому пособствует не только делфи, но и ее вклад в это тоже есть)

Comment: Как сказал Пользователь ранее динамические -- array of type
и создание -- setlength

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
var 
  i: Integer;
...
{$R-}
i:=2;
a[i]:=1;
```

ЗЫ и когда ж мы увидим хоть одного такого преподавателя на хэшкоде с его методичкой... пусть бы объяснил причины своего существования.

Comment: Спасибо, так работает.